# WebAssembly: worker.js onmessage() captured an uncaught exception: NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten

I have a working C++ static library that I'm porting to WebAssembly using Emscripten. Right now, I'm trying to get its existing unit tests running.

I'm using the following Python script to serve the HTML file Emscripten generated.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, test

class CORSRequestHandler (SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers (self):
        self.send_header("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp")
        self.send_header("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin")

        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Handler = CORSRequestHandler
    Handler.extensions_map[".js"] = "application/javascript"
    Handler.extensions_map[".wasm"] = "application/wasm"

    test(Handler, HTTPServer, port=int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 8000)
```

However, when I navigate to `http://localhost:8000/ExampleTests.html`, I see a series of errors in the console.

````
ExampleTests.worker.js:105 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8000/ExampleTests.js' because its MIME type ('application/wasm') is not executable.
worker.js onmessage() captured an uncaught exception: NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:8000/ExampleTests.js' failed to load.```
````

Here's the failing function, `onmessage()`, from `ExampleTests.worker.js`:

```js
self.onmessage = function(e) {
  try {
    if (e.data.cmd === 'load') { // Preload command that is called once per worker to parse and load the Emscripten code.

      // Module and memory were sent from main thread
      Module['wasmModule'] = e.data.wasmModule;

      Module['wasmMemory'] = e.data.wasmMemory;

      Module['buffer'] = Module['wasmMemory'].buffer;

      Module['ENVIRONMENT_IS_PTHREAD'] = true;

      if (typeof e.data.urlOrBlob === 'string') {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(e.data);
        console.log(e.data.urlOrBlob);
        importScripts(e.data.urlOrBlob);
      } else {
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(e.data.urlOrBlob);
        importScripts(objectUrl);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
      }
    } else if (e.data.cmd === 'run') {
      // This worker was idle, and now should start executing its pthread entry
      // point.
      // performance.now() is specced to return a wallclock time in msecs since
      // that Web Worker/main thread launched. However for pthreads this can
      // cause subtle problems in emscripten_get_now() as this essentially
      // would measure time from pthread_create(), meaning that the clocks
      // between each threads would be wildly out of sync. Therefore sync all
      // pthreads to the clock on the main browser thread, so that different
      // threads see a somewhat coherent clock across each of them
      // (+/- 0.1msecs in testing).
      Module['__performance_now_clock_drift'] = performance.now() - e.data.time;

      // Pass the thread address inside the asm.js scope to store it for fast access that avoids the need for a FFI out.
      Module['__emscripten_thread_init'](e.data.threadInfoStruct, /*isMainBrowserThread=*/0, /*isMainRuntimeThread=*/0);

      // Establish the stack frame for this thread in global scope
      // The stack grows downwards
      var max = e.data.stackBase;
      var top = e.data.stackBase + e.data.stackSize;
      assert(e.data.threadInfoStruct);
      assert(top != 0);
      assert(max != 0);
      assert(top > max);
      // Also call inside JS module to set up the stack frame for this pthread in JS module scope
      Module['establishStackSpace'](top, max);
      Module['PThread'].receiveObjectTransfer(e.data);
      Module['PThread'].threadInit();

      // Embind must initialize itself on all threads, as it generates support JS.
      // We only do this once per worker since they get reused
      if (!initializedJS) {
        Module['___embind_register_native_and_builtin_types']();
        initializedJS = true;
      }

      try {
        // pthread entry points are always of signature 'void *ThreadMain(void *arg)'
        // Native codebases sometimes spawn threads with other thread entry point signatures,
        // such as void ThreadMain(void *arg), void *ThreadMain(), or void ThreadMain().
        // That is not acceptable per C/C++ specification, but x86 compiler ABI extensions
        // enable that to work. If you find the following line to crash, either change the signature
        // to "proper" void *ThreadMain(void *arg) form, or try linking with the Emscripten linker
        // flag -s EMULATE_FUNCTION_POINTER_CASTS=1 to add in emulation for this x86 ABI extension.
        var result = Module['invokeEntryPoint'](e.data.start_routine, e.data.arg);

        Module['checkStackCookie']();
        if (Module['keepRuntimeAlive']()) {
          Module['PThread'].setExitStatus(result);
        } else {
          Module['__emscripten_thread_exit'](result);
        }
      } catch(ex) {
        if (ex != 'unwind') {
          // FIXME(sbc): Figure out if this is still needed or useful.  Its not
          // clear to me how this check could ever fail.  In order to get into
          // this try/catch block at all we have already called bunch of
          // functions on `Module`.. why is this one special?
          if (typeof(Module['_emscripten_futex_wake']) !== 'function') {
            err("Thread Initialisation failed.");
            throw ex;
          }
          // ExitStatus not present in MINIMAL_RUNTIME
          if (ex instanceof Module['ExitStatus']) {
            if (Module['keepRuntimeAlive']()) {
              err('Pthread 0x' + Module['_pthread_self']().toString(16) + ' called exit(), staying alive due to noExitRuntime.');
            } else {
              err('Pthread 0x' + Module['_pthread_self']().toString(16) + ' called exit(), calling _emscripten_thread_exit.');
              Module['__emscripten_thread_exit'](ex.status);
            }
          }
          else
          {
            Module['__emscripten_thread_exit'](-2);
            throw ex;
          }
        } else {
          // else e == 'unwind', and we should fall through here and keep the pthread alive for asynchronous events.
          err('Pthread 0x' + Module['_pthread_self']().toString(16) + ' completed its main entry point with an `unwind`, keeping the worker alive for asynchronous operation.');
        }
      }
    } else if (e.data.cmd === 'cancel') { // Main thread is asking for a pthread_cancel() on this thread.
      if (Module['_pthread_self']()) {
        Module['__emscripten_thread_exit'](-1/*PTHREAD_CANCELED*/);
      }
      postMessage({ 'cmd': 'cancelDone' });
    } else if (e.data.target === 'setimmediate') {
      // no-op
    } else if (e.data.cmd === 'processThreadQueue') {
      if (Module['_pthread_self']()) { // If this thread is actually running?
        Module['_emscripten_current_thread_process_queued_calls']();
      }
    } else {
      err('worker.js received unknown command ' + e.data.cmd);
      err(e.data);
    }
  } catch(ex) {
    err('worker.js onmessage() captured an uncaught exception: ' + ex);
    if (ex && ex.stack) err(ex.stack);
    throw ex;
  }
};
```

`importScripts(e.data.urlOrBlob);` is the failing line, so I added some additional console log messages (which you can see in the code snippet). Here's the output of those logs messages:

```
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: {…}, origin: '', lastEventId: '', source: null, …}
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope {name: '', onmessageerror: null, onmessage: ƒ, cancelAnimationFrame: ƒ, close: ƒ, …}
data: {cmd: 'load', urlOrBlob: 'http://localhost:8000/ExampleTests.js', wasmMemory: Memory(256), wasmModule: Module}
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
lastEventId: ""
origin: ""
path: []
ports: []
returnValue: true
source: null
srcElement: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope {name: '', onmessageerror: null, onmessage: ƒ, cancelAnimationFrame: ƒ, close: ƒ, …}
target: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope {name: '', onmessageerror: null, onmessage: ƒ, cancelAnimationFrame: ƒ, close: ƒ, …}
timeStamp: 0
type: "message"
userActivation: null
[[Prototype]]: MessageEvent
```

```
{cmd: 'load', urlOrBlob: 'http://localhost:8000/ExampleTests.js', wasmMemory: Memory(256), wasmModule: Module}
cmd: "load"
urlOrBlob: "http://localhost:8000/ExampleTests.js"
wasmMemory: 
Memory(256)
wasmModule: Module {}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

```
http://localhost:8000/ExampleTests.js
```

---

Does anyone know why http://localhost:8000/ExampleTests.js is failing to load?

Is there any additional information that would be helpful for debugging?

Comment: Not 100% sure but this might be issue because its MIME type ('application/wasm') is not executable.. Can you try to return here 'application/javascript.'

Comment: @DraganS Nope, that's a bad idea. Wasm should always be served with application/wasm.

Comment: What happens when you try to visit http://localhost:8000/ExampleTests.js directly in the browser? Does it return any error? Do you see anything in Python server logs?

Comment: My app (based on Rust) has 1) Request URL: http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/wasm_pkg_mame_renderer_js.js => Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8 -- 2) Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/wasm => Content-Type: application/wasm. Guess WASM resource is not mapped to ext. js.